# PHP stops after return

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP function that displays an error message as part of form validation, I have mixed in some HTML to create a page for it;

```
  function displayMessage($msg)
  {
      ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>          
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
        <title>Error sending message</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;font-family:arial;font-size:16px;color:#333333;background:#ffe6e3;padding:10px;background:#ffe6e3;border:1px solid #fb8d8d;">
        <?php return $msg;  ?>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
      <?php
  }
```

When the code is run everything looks right in the browser, however, looking at the source code it stops right after the message is displayed so the closing div, body, and html tags are not shown.

How do I get them to show, I have tried echo instead of return but that displays the error message but still processes the form.

Comment: How are you calling `displayMessage()`?

Comment: i think you mean to use `echo` not `return`. Regardless, this is not correct. You are thinking PHP is like JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using functions incorrectly, (similar to a `require_once`). Functions are meant to be called and return a value, not used to include dynamic code in this manner. The reason why it stops after `return $msg` is because you are telling the function to return a variable called $msg and end further execution of the function block.

I'd suggest using something like this

```
  function displayMessage($msg)
  {
      $html = <<<EOD
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>          
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
        <title>Error sending message</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;font-family:arial;font-size:16px;color:#333333;background:#ffe6e3;padding:10px;background:#ffe6e3;border:1px solid #fb8d8d;">
         $msg;
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
      EOD;
    return $html;
  }
echo displayMessage($msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` from a function means `instantly going back to whoever called it`. Means none of the lines below `return` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the below:

```
<?php return $msg; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php echo $msg; ?>
```

The `return` keyword should be used only inside a function call.

Answer (score 1):

`return` means "return this value from the function, and stop executing the function". The keyword that you're actually looking for is `echo`:

```php
function displayMessage($msg)
{
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>          
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
    <title>Error sending message</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;font-family:arial;font-size:16px;color:#333333;background:#ffe6e3;padding:10px;background:#ffe6e3;border:1px solid #fb8d8d;">
    <?php echo $msg;  ?>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use a `return`, change to `echo`. `return` means that you want return something to outside of the function. One way of use a return would be:

```
    function displayMessage($msg)
      {
          return '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head>          
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
            <title>Error sending message</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          </head>
          <body>
          <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;font-family:arial;font-size:16px;color:#333333;background:#ffe6e3;padding:10px;background:#ffe6e3;border:1px solid #fb8d8d;">
          '.$msg.'
          </div>
          </body>
          </html>';
      }
```

And when you call the function you just do:

```
<?php echo displayMessage(); ?>
```

Or you can change to `echo`:

```
function displayMessage($msg)
  {
      echo '
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>          
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
        <title>Error sending message</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;font-family:arial;font-size:16px;color:#333333;background:#ffe6e3;padding:10px;background:#ffe6e3;border:1px solid #fb8d8d;">
        '.$msg.'
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>'
  }
```

And call the function:

```
<?php displayMessage(); ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Yeah, you right. But I thought that he gonna do the research of the echo function. Next time I will post the whole answer.

Comment: you can EDIT your answer

Comment: Is it better this way?